# Snap Store no funciona correctamente en Debian

Tags: linux, debian

acabo de instalar snap store en debian mediante snap pero al abrir snap store me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si intento buscar las aplicaciones que deseo instalar no me sale ningún resultado y si busco aplicaciones como Visual Studio code tampoco aparecen.
Solo aparecen 8 aplicaciones en la snap store. Ni los iconos me cargan.

Si intento abrir la snap store desde la terminal me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cómo solucionar este error.

Comment: No tengo experiencia con *snap* pero valdría la pena preguntar: algún problema con los paquetes que maneja debian y manejarlos con `apt`?

Comment: Hola, no he tenido ningún problema con los paquetes que maneja debian, ni ningún problema con apt. pero el único problema es snap store ya que no cargan los iconos ni las aplicaciones de la tienda.

Comment: El problema no tiene relación con programación, así que es posible que cierren la pregunta. Tampoco tenemos SuperUser en español. Lo que sí te recomiendo es hacerle seguimiento a [este bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=934372) en la lista de correo de Debian

Comment: ¿Instalaste el servicio [snap](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-debian)?

Comment: bueno, creo que reportare el problema a debian usando [reportbug](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting.es.html)

Comment: si instale el servicio de snap atravez de apt usando la guía de instalación de snap, pero no he probado instalando [hello-world](https://snapcraft.io/hello-world) con snap para probar si funciona correctamente.